# Is there some way to use 08 and 09 and get rid of invalid digit "8" in octal constant error?

Tags: c

I am getting this error:-invalid digit "8" in octal constant, I read the reason behind this and as everyone suggested I should not use 08, instead of this I should simply use 8. Although I am making program related to Gregorian calendar and I have to give input in DD/MM/YYYY format, so for month I have to give 08 and 09. So is there some way to use it? I am using 08 and 09 in switch case.

```
switch (month){
    case 01:
        month =0;
        break;
    case 02:
    case 03:
        month =3;
        break;
    case 04:
        month =6;
        break;
    case 05:
        month =1;
        break;
    case 06:
        month = 4;
        break;
    case 07:
        month = 6;
        break;
    case 08:
        month = 2;
        break;
    case 09:
        month = 5;
        break;
    case 10:    
        month = 0;
        break;
```

....

Comment: In C source code — no.  In `scanf()`, use `%d` and not `%i` or `%o`.  But it isn't very clear from your question what the context is.  You should show how you are using `08` so we can see better what your options might be.

Comment: For scanf I am using %d.

Comment: Where are you getting the 'invalid digit 8 in octal constant' messages from?  The compiler?  Can you show the code?  You should really produce an MCVE ([MCVE]) to illustrate the problem.  It needn't have much to do with your real code — and it might be all of 10 lines of C.

Comment: Yes please have a look on this switch case, apart from this code is running fine.

Comment: Take the leading zeros off in your `case` labels.

Comment: "Octal" is one of the many possible text representations of a number. I assume your `month` variable is a number. You don't have any reason to think of it as `01`, `02` etc.

Comment: You could code the switch as an array: `int month_map[13] = { -1, 0, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5 };` and `assert(month > 0 && month < 13); month == month_map[month];`.  Since you seem to be coding the 'day of week' for '1st day of month' for 2017 in the switch, there are better ways to deal with that altogether, that won't require recompilation in 2018 and will work with any arbitrary year (in the range of years from, say, 1850 to 9999).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan it's somewhat working, I will check the rest. :)

Comment: Any number literal that starts with a `0` is considered an octal number by the compiler. That includes numbers that you think are decimal, like `09`. Change it to `9`.

Answer (score 1):

Treat your input as strings, not as numbers.  Then convert your strings into numbers.